# Bandwidth speed test with nginx

Tags: perl, nginx, lua

I have server with nginx-1.4.1.

I want to test bandwidth between my desktop and server.

Incoming speed I can test by simple download file with size 10M from server and count time what I need to this.

But also I need test upload speed, but nginx by default can`t upload file.

I try with this config:

```
location /upload {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        return 200 ok;
}
```

But when I try upload some file to server with `curl "http://server_name/upload" --data @downloads/smric-6_0_3.tar.gz -i -v -H 'Content-Length: 20490365'` I see what nginx answer before get body of request.

Can I realize upload speed test only with nginx and curl or I need use some programing language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solutions to this problem with using perl.

```
http {

....

perl_modules perl;
perl_require upload.pm;

    server {
    ...
        location /http {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            autoindex on;

        }
        location /ping {
                return 200 Ok;
        }
        location /download {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/test_file.bin;
        }
        location /upload {
                perl upload::handler;
                client_max_body_size 100m;
        }
    }
}
```

And perl script:

```
package upload;

use nginx;

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;

    if ($r->request_method ne "POST") {
        return DECLINED;
    }

    if ($r->has_request_body(\&post)) {
        return OK;
    }

    return HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
}

sub post {
    my $r = shift;

    $r->send_http_header;

    $r->print("Ok\n");

    return OK;
}

1;

__END__
```